# Why is Rails apparently changing my database password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I really don't understand what's happening here... It's a nightmare!

I have the following in my databasae.yml of the rails app

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: segnalazioni_dev
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: 04210
  port: 5432
  timeout: 5000
```

but when I go for a `rake db:create` I get an authentication error, in which the **used pasword is different** from `04210`:

```
    Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", 
"database"=>"segnalazioni_test", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"postgres", 
"password"=>2184, "port"=>5432, "timeout"=>5000}
```

As you can see the password is changed to from `04210` to `2184`. I tried to put other passwords in the database.yml file, and as long as they don't start with a 0 they are then used in the rake db command, as it should be. But the password of my postgres user is 04210, I need to use that one!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you're using the *number* `04210` instead of the *string* `"04210"`. The YAML interpreter is reading "04210" as an octal value, **[which is 2184 in base 10](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2184+in+base+8)**, so "2184" shows up.

To fix this, either pick a numeric password that doesn't start with a zero, or change your database.yml to use the string:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: segnalazioni_dev
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: "04210"              # Now it's a string instead of a number.
  port: 5432
  timeout: 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the clue not in the database name?  Looks like you're running in Test not Development, no?